# WPF Namespace question - Process?

Tags: wpf

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    Process virtualMouse = new Process(); 

    virtualMouse.StartInfo.FileName = "VirtualMouse.exe"; // Needs to be full path 
    virtualMouse.StartInfo.Arguments = ""; // If you have any arguments 

    bool result = virtualMouse.Start(); 
}
```

but  iam getting error

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what error you're getting but the Process you are looking for is [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx).

Comment: iam usig WPF and the error iam getting is : type or namespace name 'Process' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Have you tried adding `using System.Diagnostics;` to your code?