# how to launch other program in WPF like windows form process.start

Tags: wpf

i used process.start in windows form to launch other program but now i want to use wpf to launch it .
i uesd: Process virtualMouse = new Process();

```
virtual.StartInfo.FileName = "VirtualMouse.exe";    
bool result = virtual.Start();
```

and i getting error:

the type or namespace name'Process' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

how to do it in wpf??

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Namespace question - Process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078483/wpf-namespace-question-process)

Answer (score 3):

It's just the same way as in Windows Forms. You need to add a `using` directive at the top of the file to `System.Diagnostics`.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add System.Diagnostics namespace to your source file.